# ¿Cómo puedo limpiar un array al pasar de un modal a otro?

Tags: javascript

tengo un procedimiento que en un modal al dar click en eliminar los datos de una tabla se vaya almacenando sus valores en un array pero al pasar a otro modal que hace exactamente lo mismo, la variable aun sigue almacenando los datos anteriores cuando en este modal quiero los datos exclusivamente de este modal, ayuda por favor.

**Almacenar informacion al dar click en un botón de eliminar para guardar su valor**

```
let metros = [];
            
            
            $('#modalEditarOtPloteo').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                
                $(document).on('click', '#eliminarMetros', function () {
                    
                    metros.push($(this).attr('value'))
                    console.log(metros);
                })
            })
            
            $('#modalEditarOtPloteo').modal('show')
```

Comment: Dentro de la función que abre el modal, inmediatamente reinicializa la variable: `metros = [];`. Y elimina de ahí la función `$(document).on()`.

Comment: @Triby intente pero no funciona compa ahora el array sale repetido sin la informacion por ejemplo, al abrir un modal sale Array[undefined], cuando abro otro modal sale Array[undefined] Array[undefined]